# Last variable is selected, rather than the one I select, and strftime gives the time the app is opened not the time clicked

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, local-variables, strftime

I'm building a simple app for the sake of practicing Python3 and to ease some repetitive things that I type often through the day.

My very limited programming background is mostly with batch files.

The idea is to click a button and it sends either a formatted block of text or a formatted 'date statuscode time timezone' code to the clipboard. I have the formatting worked out, and can get text copied to the clipboard.

Present issues are:

The time stamp I get represents the time the app was started, not the time the button is clicked.

The last variable in the list is the one that gets copied regardless of what button I click in the "app".

In my actual app I have a variables document that holds all the codes I want to copy rather than all being in the same script, but the issues are the same.

```
# Imports
from tkinter import *
from datetime import *

#Status Codes:
ipro = ' IPRO '
rslv = ' RSLV '

#note codes:
visit = ' Visit '

#quitting the application:
stop = ' Quit '

# Time stuff
this = datetime.now()
date1 = (this.strftime("%y/%m/%d"))
date2 = (this.strftime("%H%M"))

#Notes:
visit_note = '''Visited the area.'''

#Action Codes
ipro_act = (date1 + ipro + date2 + ' CT')
rslv_act = (date1 + rslv + date2 + ' CT')


# Get a box
window = Tk()
iproBtn = Button(window, text=ipro, width=8)
rslvBtn = Button(window, text=rslv, width=8)
visitBtn = Button(window, text=visit, width=8)
stopBtn = Button(window, text=stop, width=8)

# Cut a hole in the box
iproBtn.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
rslvBtn.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=5)
visitBtn.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=5)
stopBtn.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=5)

# Wrapping paper the box
window.title('App')
window.resizable(0, 0)


# Clipboard Action / Open the box / copies statCode to the clipboard
def clip_act(magnus):
    r = Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    r.clipboard_clear()
    r.clipboard_append(magnus)
    r.clipboard_get()


# configure the button to the action
iproBtn.configure(command = clip_act(ipro_act))
rslvBtn.configure(command=(clip_act(rslv_act)))
visitBtn.configure(command=(clip_act(visit_note)))
#^last item is the one that gets copied regardless of the button clicked.
stopBtn.configure(command=(quit))


# Sustain window:
window.mainloop()
```

Things I've tried:

Moving the button.configs around. Last in the list is always the one selected. I know this should be a huge hint as to what is broken and why, but I can't seem to figure out what, and I'm really not sure what to search for to find a solution.

Searches I've made trying to find some breadcrumbs toward answers:

(many)Variations on: 
"last variable is always the one selected..."
"strftime gives the time the app is opened not the time it is evoked."

In the end I want to copy text to the clipboard relevant to the clicked button, and want the timestamp to reflect the time the button is clicked.

Comment: Well, your `date1` and `date2` never get updated to their latest. They are always their initial objects. You need to assign the latest value manually they're not in sync with the right-hand side of their `=` assignment.

Comment: Please try to provide [mcve].

Comment: for debugging whats going one you should implement some `print` statements and use an editor for seeing out aside your code.